# Chart.js Using A JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an array of objects that have an x and y property. How do I get the correct property values to be used in the correct places in a chart.js chart?

I have the following .js code so far

```
var lineChartData = {
labels: progress.y,
datasets: [{
    label: 'My First dataset',
    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
    fill: false,
    data: progress,
    yAxisID: 'y-axis-1'
   }]
};
```

The array object is called `progress`. I think the `data: progress` is picking up the x property value automatically, but the `labels: progress.y` isn't.

Any ideas how I get the y axis label to work?

EDIT: The progress object looks like this when I view the page source

```
var progress = [{"y":1624,"x":0},{"y":1606,"x":1}, etc
```

Comment: Are you able to post the `progress` object? Is it showing the dataset?

Comment: I've updated with how the progress object looks.

Comment: Never mind I got the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just selected the x property from the array like so:

```
labels: progress.map(function (a) { return a.x; })
```

Answer (score 0):

Using objects is possible in Chart.js **3.x** and it can be an advantage (e.g. use other properties for tooltips).

Use `parsing` to specify the property for axes.

Example from chartjs.org:

```
type: 'bar',
data: {
    datasets: [{
        data: [{id: 'Sales', nested: {value: 1500}}, {id: 'Purchases', nested: {value: 500}}]
    }]
},
options: {
    parsing: {
        xAxisKey: 'id',
        yAxisKey: 'nested.value'
    }
}
```

Example 2 from chartjs.org:

```
const data = [{x: 'Jan', net: 100, cogs: 50, gm: 50}, {x: 'Feb', net: 120, cogs: 55, gm: 75}];
const cfg = {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Jan', 'Feb'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Net sales',
            data: data,
            parsing: {
                yAxisKey: 'net'
            }
        }, {
            label: 'Cost of goods sold',
            data: data,
            parsing: {
                yAxisKey: 'cogs'
            }
        }, {
            label: 'Gross margin',
            data: data,
            parsing: {
                yAxisKey: 'gm'
            }
        }]
    },
};
```